# ¿como muestro la informacion de una tabla por medio de la llave foranea?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto para ir practicando **laravel**.

En mi proyecto tengo dos modelos llamados **catalogos** y **descripciones**  relacionadas de **1:N**, lo que intento es que en mi vista donde muestro los registros de las descripciones en ves de mostrar la **llave foranea** de la vista de **catalogos** me muestre el registro a la que pertenece.

**modelo de catalogos**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Catalogo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'catalogos';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['Nombre'];

    public function descripcion(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Descripcione','catalogo_id');
    }
}
```

**modelo de descripciones**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Descripcione extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'descripciones';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['catalogo_id','Descripcion'];

    public function catalogo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Catalogo');
    }
}
```

**controlador de descripciones**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    use App\catalogo;
    use App\Descripcione;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class DescripcionesController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
        {

            return view('descripciones.index',compact('descripciones','catalogo'));
        }
     }
```

**mi tabla del index de la vista de descripciones**

```
@foreach($descripciones as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->catalogo_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->Descripcion }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ url('/descripciones/' . $item->id) }}" title="View Descripcione"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> View</button></a>
        <a href="{{ url('/descripciones/' . $item->id . '/edit') }}" title="Edit Descripcione"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button></a>

        <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/descripciones' . '/' . $item->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete Descripcione" onclick="return confirm(&quot;Confirm delete?&quot;)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

me gustaria que en vez de la llave foranea se muestre la informacion a la que le pertenece... como podria hacerlo????

Comment: es decir lo que buscas es mostrar información a la que pertenece en vez de `catalogo_id`?

Comment: ¿La consulta que tratas de hacer es al modelo `Descripcione` y de ahi traer todos sus catálogos?

Comment: asi es ... es que estoy intentando pero aun asi no logro visualizarlo